# What does "hom" stand for in hom-sets and hom-functors?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, math-history

With given category $\mathcal{C}$ and its objects $A$ and $B$, a *hom-set* $\hom_\mathcal{C}(A, B)$ is the collection of all morphisms from $A$ to $B$.  There is also a related notion of *hom-functor* from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{Set}$, which map objects into related hom-sets.

But why the name "*hom*"? Who was the first to use this terminology and in what context?

Comment: homomorphism (of rings, groups) I suppose

Comment: It is an apocope of *homomorphism*, that seems pretty clear…

Comment: Alternatively, in the fundamental groupoid of a topological space, $\mathsf{hom}(x,y)$ are the "**hom**otopy classes of paths from $x$ to $y$".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"Hom" stands for homomorphism, the usual name for structure preserving functions in algebra. I believe the terminology goes back to Eilenberg and Mac Lane's original article on category theory. Of course, in an arbitrary category the objects need not have structure, and the morphisms need not even be functions. Thus the terminology "morphisms" for the arrows in a category. Some texts use $Mor(x,y)$ instead of $Hom(x,y)$. It is also common to be more agnostic and simply write $C(a,b)$ for the morphisms from $a$ to $b$ in the category $C$.

Comment: What is meant by "Of course, in an arbitrary category the objects need not have structure"?

Comment: the objects can be anything at all. For instance, the objects of a category could be the letters $a,b,c$. No structure, just symbols.

Comment: I would say that the hom-sets are the structure on the objects.

Comment: that may be a bit misleading. The hom sets are the categorical structure on the objects induced by *that* particular category. Different categories may have the same objects, so the objects themselves do not have structure.

Comment: Yes, sure, I fix a category ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think Ittay means that arbitrary categories need not be enriched over other categories.  Wouldn't you agree?